# Metric for ordinal, non-normal distribution in Markov models

Tags: probability, ordinal-data, markov-process

I am working with Markov models with ordinal, non-normal distributions of probabilities.   Ultimately, I would like to create a metric for determining the probability of a specific path occurring.   At any given point along the path, there is a range of possible moves with associated probabilities.  However, these are not normal distributions which makes it difficult to discuss their statistical likelihood.

I would like to create some type of metric that would measure the amount of "deviation" from more probable paths.   Because the data varies so drastically, it is difficult to get a good idea of how likely each event was.   A sampling distribution doesn't say much because variation from one path to the next path could be a difference of up to 60%.   Also, at each state there might be one possible move or 30.   This high degree of variation between states makes it difficult to measure.